# Did Freezer surpassed Goku and Vegeta's power level again in Dragon Ball Super Broly?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

In Dragon Ball Super Broly,

> When Goku and Vegeta fighting together can't defeat Broly, Freezer holds his own against him for half an hour supposedly.

Did Freezer surpassed Goku and Vegeta's power level again in Dragon Ball Super Broly?

Answer (score 1):

Frieza actually lasts for an **Hour**(They had 2 failed fusions). However, Goku and Vegeta didn't really faint or get injured immensely(Note: This is based on the level of injuries they've had in some of the previous arcs) and we don't really see them in a position unable to fight or even really fight to try to last against Broly to make that argument. Goku knew that they couldn't defeat Broly in this state and needed to fuse. Hence, they teleported out of there. Goku and Vegeta have shown far greater resilience against substantially much higher levels of power. This was more of Goku making the best use of the situation and doing what was necessary.

Plus, when Broly initially loses to Vegeta and Paragus says Broly has reached his limit, Frieza decides to retreat. If Frieza was substantially stronger, I don't see why he wouldn't have jumped into the fight at that point in time and defeated Goku and Vegeta.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure that answer is precisely true. Frieza may have been more powerful than Goku or Vegeta individually, but knowing he’d have to fight both of them, and having seen them break their limits time and time again in the past, he might have deemed it too risky to try and take them on.

Even later when it seemed like Blue Goku was overpowering Broly, Paragus already told Frieza that Broly was out of control, so it’s not at all guaranteed it would have been a 2v2.

Of course, it certainly could be the case that Frieza was simply on the same level as Goku or Vegeta and had thick plot armor to make the gag work (it was pretty funny), but based on feats here Frieza seems stronger.